# Do I need to import React for stateless functional components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

All around me (e.g. blog posts, code) I see code for React stateless functional components in which `React` is imported even though it's never used.

```
import React from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  return <div>Howdy!</div>;
}

export default MyComponent;
```

I'm wondering why we need to import React when it's not actually used (in any explicit manner).

I'm also surprised that my linter doesn't complain about the un-used import.

Is there some reason to import `React` into functional components that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Did you actually try to transpile it? I mean, intellectual arguing is all well and good, but simply trying it would have answered the question.

Comment: The ESLint React plugin, eslint-plugin-react, exposes the rule [react/react-in-jsx-scope](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/react-in-jsx-scope.md) to ensure you have `React` in scope when using JSX because the compiled code references`React`. The description of that rule also answers your question. The [react/jsx-uses-react](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-uses-react.md) rule prevents `React` from being marked as unused.

Comment: @DaveNewton: works fine on my system.  that's why i was confused...

Comment: Without the import? I don't see how.

Comment: @DaveNewton: i'm guessing Babel handles it under the hood

Comment: @sfletche Must be a later version; I'll check it out--it definitely complains if we don't explicitly import `React` in our current build config.

Comment: Small comment off topic, but important:
React.PropTypes has moved into a different package since React v15.5. Please use the prop-types library instead.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Yes, there is. Babel transpiles JSX to *use* `React`:

```
<div></div>
```

To:

```
React.createElement("div", null);
```

So your JSX is internally transpiled to use `React.createElement` in pure JavaScript, which *does* use `React`. Remember that JSX is just syntactic sugar over pure JavaScript.  If you don't specifically import it, it will report that `React` isn't defined.

**Update Sep 2021:** In React 17, a new JSX transform is introduced which automatically transforms JSX without using `React.createElement`. This allows us to use JSX without importing React. More on [docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html)

Answer (score 23):

As of now you don't need to `import React from 'react';`
for functional components. Why you needed it is well explained in accepted answer.

This official blog post https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html
explains why it was needed and now after version 17 it is no longer needed.

Comment: Excellent news!  Good to know!

Comment: Actually Babel will automatically imports "react" (or other libraries which support the new API) when needed, so you don't have to manually include it anymore.

But concept is still same inside - React will be in scope in traspiled code.

Comment: Experience confirms this for me. Interestingly, despite not being the newest, accepted, or highest upvoted, this answer was the featured snippet for the search: "do you need to import react for functional components".

Answer (score 6):

> What exactly a React Stateless Functional Component is?

When you write a stateful component it has basic these three parts (other than all the logic):

**1.** constructor

**2.** lifecycle methods

**3.** render

And react convert this render part into:

```
React.createElement(element, null); //element will be the wrapper of all the jsx
```

Now when you write a Stateless Functional Component it basically has only a `render` part **no constructor, no lifecycle method**. Whatever you `return` from this component will also get converted into:

```
React.createElement(element, null);
```

So that's why importing `React` is required. Always keep in mind that **we write JSX not html**, that will get transpiled by [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-jsx/).

Check the [DOC for React without JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-jsx.html).

Check the [converted version](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=function%20a()%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20%3Cdiv%3E%20hello%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%7D) of a functional component by Babel.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: "Whatever you return from this component will also get converted into:React.createElement(element, null)". How does it get converted to createElement?

Comment: @Prakashsharma because we write jsx not html, check this: write a functional component and check the converted output: https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=function%20a()%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20%3Cdiv%3E%20hello%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%7D

Comment: So babel is transpiling that. You have actually solved my multiple doubts. Thanks. :D

Comment: glad, it helped you :)

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need to, React **17** does it automatically with the help of out of the box **JSX Transform**.

[Find this article here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's more or less a duplicate of @foolish's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64735059/7451109)