# why do we need to import React from "react" in the file having extension .jsx? it seems there is no difference between the .jsx and .js extensions.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

[image]

### usually we do it for writing JSX syntax inside .js  files.

## ...but here I'm already giving the extension as .jsx then why we need to import react module ?

I've tried to search for the answer but everywhere i found it unclear.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44141010/do-i-need-to-import-react-for-stateless-functional-components

Comment: In short, behind the JSX grammar, it's calling `React.createElement()`, this is where the imported `React` is used.

Answer (score 0):

This is because JSX is included in the react library, it won't work if you don't have `import React from 'react'` at the top of your file. Creating a file with a `jsx` or `tsx` extension does only define what content will be inside the file and helps your IDE provide file icons, syntax highlighting etc.

###### Interesting Fact

Some frameworks like Next.js do this automatically and you are not required to import react at all, Next.js even defines the type react as an UMD global so you do not need to separately import type definitions.

Comment: Also, after React 17, explicit `import React from 'react'` is no more needed.

Comment: @Megrax Yes, that is also true, although I think Next.js already provided this functionality before React 17.

Comment: *"This is because JSX is included in the react library"* I think that's a bit confusing. React is mostly a runtime library (so far). JSX doesn't exist at runtime, so React doesn't really anything about JSX.

Comment: @FelixKling This section was extracted from the official [react-native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/intro-react#:~:text=Because%20JSX%20is%20included%20in,the%20top%20of%20your%20file!).

Comment: ...then there is no difference between the .js and .jsx extensions apparently?

Comment: @Balaji As far as I know if you use Typescript in combination with JSX your IDE will freak out if you try to write JSX in a normal `.ts` file. I don't know if the same applies for `.js` files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need that because you've already imported the React in the app.js file.

Comment: No, Its not working that way.

Comment: Thank you, can you show me how to work ?